# Multiple Context Loader definition error in tomcat

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, servletcontextlistener

I have a ApplicationInitializer class that implements WebApplicationInitializer and in it I am adding my own ContextLoaderListener. When I am running my app in STS it is running perfectly, but when I try to deploy the war file in my tomcat, the application does not deploy and gives the following multiple context listener error:

```
10-Oct-2019 10:51:58.252 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log 3 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
10-Oct-2019 10:52:05.987 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
10-Oct-2019 10:52:11.237 SEVERE [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot initialize context because there is already a root application context present - check whether you have multiple ContextLoader* definitions in your web.xml!
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:262)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4683)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5146)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:978)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1849)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:773)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:427)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1620)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1151)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1353)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1357)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1335)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
10-Oct-2019 10:52:11.240 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
```

I read the following documentation:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file

From what I understood is I can completely remove my AppInitializer class and add its contents in the spring boot application class. Then I looked at how the onStartup of SpringBootServletInitializer was done and changed my code to:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan("com.example")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example")
@ComponentScan("com.example")
@EnableConfigurationProperties(CustomProperties.class)
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(final ServletContext sc) throws ServletException{

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext root = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

        root.scan("com.example");
        sc.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(root){
            @Override
            public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
                // no-op because the application context is already initialized
            }
        });

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic appServlet = sc.addServlet("mvc", new DispatcherServlet(new GenericWebApplicationContext()));
        appServlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        appServlet.addMapping("/");

        sc.addFilter("securityFilter", new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain"))
        .addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

This time the war file deploys normally but when I try to hit the home page I get the following error although I did add the springSecurityFilterChain:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' available
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:771)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1221)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1111)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:337)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263)
```

This is what I had initially(two separate classes):

```java
public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(final ServletContext sc) throws ServletException{

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext root = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

        root.scan("com.example");
        sc.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(root));

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic appServlet = sc.addServlet("mvc", new DispatcherServlet(new GenericWebApplicationContext()));
        appServlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        appServlet.addMapping("/");

        sc.addFilter("securityFilter", new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain"))
        .addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
    }
}
```

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan("com.example")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example")
@ComponentScan("com.example")
@EnableConfigurationProperties(CustomProperties.class)
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer{
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Please help me figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I suggest a read of the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file) which you pointed to. As mentioned there the only thing you need to do is implement the `configure` method. Spring Boot will take care of everything else.

Comment: I did implement the configure method as explained in the doc but its still not working

Comment: You didn't according to what you posted. You overriden the `onStartup` that isn't a `configure` method and in your last snippet it is completely missing.

Comment: No what I meant was I just added it after seeing your reply and tested it but it didnt work, I'll update my initial post.

Comment: Make sure that your `Application` class is in the root package `com.example` that way you can remove the `@EntityScan`, `@ComponentScan` and `@EnableJpaRepositories`, as Spring Boot will detect and enable them automatically. Also make sure that you have Spring Security in your classpath. And remember the only thing you need is the code you have in your last class. No `onStartup` method or anything else that registers the `DelegatingFilterProxy` that is all done for you. If that isn't happening you are doing something in your code/config which disables Spring Security.

Comment: I removed the ApplicationInitiziazer class and changed the location of the Application file and removed the annotations, now although it is working fine in STS when I deploy in tomcat I get the login page and when I submit the form I get 404 Not found (The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists)